# How to set options when using browserInDocker() with WebDriverManager?

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

How can I set ChromeOptions on the driver when using .browserInDocker()? I want to set the option "--disable-dev-shm-usage" and using Docker the recommended call is:

```java
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
                                   .browserInDocker()
                                   .create()
```

However, it looks like `WebDriverManager` or `WebDriverManager.chromedriver()` do not have a way to set `ChromeOptions`.

So, how can I set extra options using WebDriverManager in Docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the method `capabilities()` for that:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver()                        
                                   .capabilities(options)
                                   .browserInDocker()
                                   .create();
```